# NTC Thermistor Resistance Calculation for circuit using Wheatstone bridge, Op Amp & Arduino

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, thermistor, wheatstone-bridge

I'm trying to work out the formula for thermistor resistance when using Wheatstone bridge/op amp circuit as opposed to a voltage divider circuit.  I know for a voltage divider the \$R_t\$ value is calculated as follows:

voltage output:

$$V_o = \frac{R_t}{R_t + R} \times Vcc$$

ADC value = \$V_i \times \frac{1023}{Vcc}\$

As \$V_o = V_i\$, these 2 formulae can be combined to give:

ADC value = \$\frac{R_t}{R_t + R} \times 1023\$
and ultimately:

$$R_t = \frac{R}{1023/ADC - 1}$$

For my circuit..

\$V_o = (\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3} - \dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1}) \times Vcc \times 10 \$ [Gain of 10]

I've combined this with \$V_i \times 1023 / Vcc \$ which gives:

$$ADC = (\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3} - \dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1}) \times 10 \times 1023 $$

Rearranging the ADC formula to isolate Rt I came up with:

$$ADC = (\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3} - \dfrac{R_2}{R_2 + R_1}) \times 10 \times 1023 $$

With a lot of help I've come up with:

$$(\dfrac{R_t}{R_t + R_3}) = (\dfrac{ADC}{10230} + \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R_2})$$

$$1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{ADC}{10230} + \dfrac{R_2}{R_1 + R2}}$$

$$1 + \dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$$

$$\dfrac{R_3}{R_t} = \dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}-\dfrac{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$$

$$\dfrac{R_3}{R_t}=\dfrac{10230(R_1+R_2)-ADC(R_1+R_2)-10230R_2}{ADC(R_1+R_2) + 10230 R_2}$$

$$R_t[10230(R_1 + R_2) - ADC(R_1 + R_2) - 10230R_2] = R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]$$

$$R_t = \dfrac{R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]}{10230(R_1 + R_2) - ADC(R_1 + R_2) - 10230R_2}$$

$$R_t = \dfrac{R_3[ADC(R_1 + R_2) + 10230R_2]}{10230 R_1 - ADC(R_1 + R_2)}$$

I don't have the actual circuit schematic to hand at the moment but, apart from the wheatstone resistors and op amp leg & feedback resistor values, it looks like this:[image]

Comment: Post your schematic. Its difficult to understand your question without that.

Comment: @nidhin Let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: Your math looks OK.. Your difference circuit is a mess!

Comment: @George Herold  Can you explain what you mean exactly I don't fully understand, I'm quite new to this?

Comment: The circuit cannot work - positive feedback. Moreover, use double voltage supply.

Comment: It would be better if you could post the original schematics.

Comment: @ nidhin Apologies but a friend has the schematic atm.  Is there anything in particular you want to know?

Comment: @George Herold Would I be right in saying that positive feedback would cause "hysterisis"?

Comment: @stevesy it would *IF* it is operating as a comparator (please don't misuse OPAMPs as comparators, I have a link somewhere that explains why not).  Are you after an analogue output or a digital output based upon predefined thresholds.

Comment: @JonRB I'm using the amp to amplify the bridge voltage (with a gain of 10) and this will go into pin A0 of the Arduino ADC?

Comment: ok so you do want an analogue signal. change that opamp feedback to be negative like others have said

Comment: @Jon RB yes it's a temperature sensor circuit, thank you.  I take it once a positive or negative voltage signal goes into the non-inverting input and is then fed back through the inverting input, that will work ok?

Comment: Try a non inverting topology as you have a x50 gain (ie >1)

Comment: @JonRB those resistor values aren't the ones I'm actually using just an example of the circuit, I've got mine set up for a gain of 10. So should I use inverting topology/negative feedback?  I'm not exactly sure why/when you choose one topology over the other.

Comment: @JonRB Can you get back to me on this if you get a chance, thanks.

Comment: Try this link... maybe help you
http://www.ametherm.com/thermistor/ntc-thermistors-temperature-measurement-with-wheatstone-bridge